# Odd string manipulation error in C#...String.Format is not working

Tags: c#, string, viewstate

We are working with a viewstate string.  This string varies in length and looks like this:

```
string Viewstate = "H4sIAAAAAAAAAO09WYwcx3W1y5sixaV4WAxNuklK3F1pODs903ORoqXlHuRauzx2SN32qqend7fFme5hd83Orhj5yGEDcpA4cRzkUBADSZAfGwiUn8SIcyBAEgiwgxjIT5wPxwgQBEgcIDDgJB9xqqqvqp7unu6eniVpaAAuZ%2Fp4VfXu9%2BpV1df%2BA%2Bzq6ODI64tviRtitimqa9kb9bdkCV760rdf%2BZ0xY7I5CsBmGwDwCUMHBUlrZY2Oml0VJdnIiu12U5FEqGhqtgZFKC%2BJqrgm6wutdvOp27osX9ca8g9Xv%2FFnX89d%2FfMDGE53AuAPh1vbtKAgmG1NlVWYvbPwkiJ3lzUNomeNe%2BDTYLTLkxeeohtuytDIQnEt21GyM%2FbLy%2FIq2PXWitIo2G9eIW8%2B49%2FUOmw1s9fQnwW13YHXlEZDVsHYek3ckKfVxoymQkXtyDaoKQLqXB9Q85reAjtX0V%2F7vSp6a0esLuyRG%2BJcQ4E2hDKBMNkHwo0ORCBuy5sQ7MY44Bkk7ACCpq8haonSupxtbfmCQe8SUDdFVW5e1bVO2wJVpLuyO35Xyvb7F0lXMpiSXbG7mhUbLUXtAfQyurUkqx3SDxNEnqdHs3eQ0RRK9Gj2RRzNoqLetd6v2O9fJl15NuJoCIT9TW1N60D8Owl53V4IDk5nYjPY4Ya8KnaacEaXkcDOon82rPnYsI72wJpTG7Tg7gBn%2FGjVMSBCW0PZyM4qG2Cvsa5157WOZr9ZjPrmgXZHX5NfFnVVUdfYt8f7DGNJNgykqgwTocU82%2BtzPeqGVlLLchuN13rTkbTnI6HPIqVYR8x9UEI9mEEqkvykGSsenMcaWkMUJQbKC7GhPG7Ioi6tIyXGADIVSKYPoBrCkgRvqDJmbvC42aFZXWs3tK5qgyohUMeDtOidBRPGApRbBnisY8j6LIFi2K%2FPJejJYWdQ3s5g1fxktM64mCG%2FWUJNRJEXog4PSsiq6CKCii8lhtKQm8qGrG8xUJ6LTe79bXFLZjnvUmwg%2BzAHMzA%2BHhvGAQxjbhMyYC7GxIo5GgYl1ZggyFh8kBodgj2SwehrrCvteV1rMVBeiAllzIaSSnda6OZgmFHUDU2RWPQO7JqUizSo8wOBKqcHqpoaqAqfGq4qAg3qmYFAlWgpfTaax1CTJV2GyNYbKsME07FBHEIgkH%2B%2Bqui9IvJsLBEx1EXRgMjz0Hv4ciAEVXO0tE3FkTYobi405hQ15Q4x4QAf15obWwaye37WPB%2FRmpsQrost2aAJH9eaH4RbbXlWk8yrtMsmROuIiY0Kq1Xj9eGAgQLdjsF2IY8AlaJ1YQ8JinIOi7wYLNmmsyuJTVltiLrLKjPWFXBIchxvhmGuDwDzCYl25hmwA3VVlCS5DdPtqgvT29XFAcCOWcaqp683BgB6hALq7ezSAHAP2%2B5gT29vDgD1KA3V291rsV284wpm%2FWXZwLGi1uy0VMbZm00ghmNt5GvVlLdlr1oqIGDT0URxrw1joI6sIq%2FeryM4tJ%2BJ1pEDNoxFxXDQPJOgM4ckgl3D2xdsqOei9eUQoZVFJao7FyN1Z0ZrtUS1caUDoaaC3Uan3nJzWZW4uSxTV%2FLVAQHk%2Bc0OBoA%2Fo863vc63fW30MZAsuTnQK5rWlEX1W5z%2B2X94739%2FMApGXgO7NsRmR95sj5De3ATknSPknQ5UmtlpXRe3CMo%2B951Tv%2FE34m%2FvACMLYKeBGQwnUEF3J86g4Wjl2u2lxZUr07WFGQiendrEXZ8SO3B9qivXp1a1ZkPWp5Cd62DHu0aCzyx5CDU45ja4qGER%2FvR%2FH37zvdz%2F%2FPso2LkA9q6LxrqEUwpgj6R1ULy5BcETJLk7hQc2VYO6oq5dWgR78c8OEgA8mFfQ4xuirogqJD832z9GHwgABKOyii%2B9xuJnQYXymqw%2F8f2v%2Ft6PPveFyigeqYUfu4vkueudVl3WP%2F%2B1r5x67Fe%2F90U7lfwZhG8H%2Bzt8aLPPaY0M9Boa1JLY3rXnH%2F%2Fyr46%2F%2Bfc7wOg8TqaJjXkUTaOoHOyD67psrCPEbbaff4GA2N3dSzJ0CCwET%2Fbkc5aml19cWZiF4AifL1b5Il8QiitCrlrhK0Ld74XpmzcXF%2BZmUcemeu4prXYzO2vmwubNi09Nt9vNrdvaXVm99t7fzV5Sf%2B2rZgL8GcB5Cf7y9Mvzi%2BKW1oEmlQEYyWY3z31zk2ZbT5LeouPXv%2FPSv%2F7bqftXbcyOIBdbRzpc1uWG8%2FII6vR5f6EhWftrhOFw6lt%2F9YM%2Fuvzl9761NApGF1FE3BQNA3ttFo%2FsN9AzDfIOBMdNrlK0qZqMOKepvC3Wm%2FKlTSIW53twJDezt8W1lzCLzG22EbUMBWkI8zOCUaODJ80%2Boic9j3X3f%2Fb17%2F3F%2F%2F3yKHnsiPOY%2B8Tv%2Fvy7tf967TvPETyg9unkYS88PD%2Fx%2BWcah%2F55519%2FEzeNh6d3XwFL5%2B53LyrGwtwVXesasj5B0IUnA7Bnjf7Juio27d%2B6fK8jG%2FCaLCLsIfZ8ffwOeufC9BpC7PgnJ98Be%2BqmFkH9eZrtDyHhfEeV8NQJerVtzpnQ6GgTLVO3uPkA4eYxk8IHmU4i6NlI0J%2ByL829%2F5U7P1NTfmAy5ItgpAseowAGpOihuNZU6lmLv21YBvMqYbm3zF6OeZl1c3Ozvdn9WfC5fvzPvcCXM3yuwtmcfPlsqoQ5i1SwOVWEu%2FsZ%2FOcW%2FrNMqyXgo5ZGXAXlo772MRSj9A%2B%2B3PDTNFIV31rFf9a9JsrCoqlUKVHG31STOe6Rv53uHODP3TdM1jZn4LDduII4L2uw81nTG6LSxGL6Dk0ec8KvjYgjAykCcUoVRJ08R3qGSROzaYz%2Bnpk2PJJfcimBjBatsMz5BnPUNYx005Tin%2B8S7BI8ItVjk5F8udWHnMcHIF212Jd0e2QkIihgDSfeabD%2F3H305G305Du9QtMOUB4vYWuNsBlbeeyx2mI6UQRnqLncqc0L3W73Ap7IvNDRUUiAHYqGP8fcBstRxJnPlEs2w%2FRt6SzSFJvd58HlCJCrpUy5ylmYxsxooxJzGZmLxSP8fZqzxmjOwnO2Ll%2FtdPnqN5ElReqNOLAMi7EfCI7h6atF5Iwgat1AJrQpbk1MXmrTumRq%2BLqkWq6TDpL31roT4LQf8nCQwPgYf4x0MsTxh966aM08Q2cO2kUa%2FvMlF02jLppstEAwct2SOUf48H%2B%2F4jP0PQkGfPQCny%2FwhXKuUuJXhHKdF6sVVwTf9xVB%2FKUZLn15MI5Ni5mfuomiJlmHWxPjN%2FM3b2o6FJtzKhayxjhtzfGb3WABG%2FOCI4%2Fe797CdvZx9lZMU%2Bt5mx3pp037%2Bknwuh%2FlTWPoiE0hw%2BerHvsaAQlYqB4jzGJWGTjlBoHyhcMwX73dZLlnNMubAhXENE8633YOwjTV0uBMI4KXzt2fOCO32nCLs4xfTUJoy07PzF1dWKnNzdxZXrj96sridO32yp3a3PL16aW5SQ4FxuzjTW1tTW4sqJx8jxt%2FddzlMaxZfwG8G4GQxQzPFxlCDqNjHroXbboXabo%2F6ZNqIklo80OQ9wZGqmOk2Y%2BjaW75KMlk2mMkmBFkKZD874aT%2FwrIIixHR2%2BAryWClQj0LWX4AuVqxWnWQ7SyU5DD6vUPfPW66VZt0rTxk8rRGFK5w7ZdFwRkrqq5Yp5f4Ut8vSzXKU2OzA%2FqsyQvoCdP3EQOpYmQ6%2BKGskZ8BlwGYwS4XLtFoinD6VcCCJGqAw97oLrWbCKka6rVTJB%2FXAO3ws0qoVi1zJn9uByhIZZKeR7aNU%2BMaHnMhFMg1bZSV2dZF3FJhutagw14v%2FDV5%2F%2FkU3%2FwwxtmrH3CCaK9z74%2F9cEX%2F%2BVHwi%2BOWoGxgXy8KAjLevoouY9d93nXIRtAiA3lrDiafySIx1YrjaTq%2Fi5489z9lm7gIJJENkvLtWkJaTdjBmEcWUbu%2FHnO9%2F5VXUQRaQPfV1QFmkkSjAb7Mcuysor%2FK%2BDL%2FZgsz%2FMZXigxen%2B4PWTZtFCCdj0dq0y%2B66qLfxpMzZ9KoOZ7qV4qJ9Xyk%2BBYD07v6M0AxXAVzPWnGXK6%2BIKry32Ae7BcsbFcCfSvsDbs8a8g2AUV2JR9FLnPBzWyUkfjuQsBhzvNoc5wy3Ib%2BX4GNzFnJVc43NJkeEDtR71dA1CvUMCu4SGCELd2EtKFlDRiPuKjJQl%2BLOdDxZpyPCAz6VWD5iDNcBq9PAJ6A3HvK4sKQpXY%2FP6u3ypc5b%2F7befN7k%2BB3WaPe%2BN7Vw1udiug1JeJ8pVMPueYFxPqWaKnbyE6LpLfKBbjHdq%2Brcuwo6ucZJZMTIwvQE4xkOZAeGhh9dHg4LoIORRVc1JTM2T8TefqZqKN6ypqQ%2BtyUONw0hjhS0aPyxxqmMNhOMfNauTVrmKsm0%2BZ%2BZznx80Y2Bssmz3kJkSifri78hbHT2IWNIcS5GfE0QbBMXKJGFU7Rp4CT%2Fuhe17TEBmJl8GEyn9KQmVXOgXboRJYh2rkjF8%2BYeQcBPvMQaMx32NiH3xvxAiRz5NLoqJyJL2psrgzJgNds2QJBttJO3aBz1XKlWouX1jJrxRLYq6e43NoDC1xsymra3AdxWx8zvbbRq4k1bOXcATeYOa6iEbsKS0O0LwNUI8xgca9UMhliiVXCUdqGavl44TwPfegT0E1axK%2F5MsOt1zdbPFBT%2B5yGwmbJ11KiaIfB89Ew%2Buc2ggg6hqQ4xG1lClW4hEVN47pesKfrug29K9vHzJ1Hx8oTeZH3YIUgaZ9fOBJcNoXrXbpPuvBfgq8EYt8Ap8plxlnNqwpTLWDhGr2JeiuIaD9gdM%2BCYlZZWPZbEfvdUgZtRvq6aRPpaI8OJUKYMIXdfQyCe7MZW7ck2paB6vx6IViXL4fvXwaxZQ7TChH34TsOg7WmP70IFQaS5Az9KNNqULRhnECinl7HUie5ryjtItuLzUJzZ%2FTw4MggwuCLuDKkYu80N68RH52ZWVtHV6sE8pckrSmpl9E6L9EXIT95u860oA0xvw0zO6BcGHNMwxkIfIB2qRlYSrAKrwOXo3FpsV8phRuFZwG2cCrWHBW99BUfcIJGTpK1lwEZIcWb%2BB6GfcbBHss0FFnIAdSHny1MVwVP4NGMpiKLxUzpWIUFU%2BawuR4gpCDWSIFPUumaOIcZqJifLf%2FtIPpXR8xPQBmyVKPE74tZBTLg5PxWcAF4tZcUMUS8k3wqViELCOhimSrrcbIbD%2BFYYuQ9Jo1VuN%2F49Gjm1vHkZxuWXDOF5XrigE1fWue0IQlnQTEWKSr8JliXxlk28PUM%2FHMrg6E3uWCCWl4nIWdjIwnEwVEYQQ1K4MGM3JkmsEvEiEMixe8aVKAoVsBn4xF2GoBy2Ro%2BEM36hKVFR7oXbhJ69cx1qVRO%2F5ZDoIYhs7kfSrwCclzHDQLkblZbXZ6eiY0PTzal74jIfRdLSalahGcCUEwKaEOIGpci1kVMpVCBKKabbpqllo5C5l1tC4126FTfvcC%2FMb0xSzXJzIddbrlKs9R%2F8DnY%2F52yFYsATTxKZYIpQmfEzIlIZQobpNnN1PS83FTXFYvYyv6AGUMfVZRs%2Br%2BP11%2B2u2nC5qklkpaR8iXI%2BkGCM4bMpV2MSYmM5ym1uxuzBBQE70pZggKlg6ZlqCyIWe4afQG%2BsJpOkmg4vXX3LK8ochdzsaeMURNk5eTapoKeCqcwcKUTR28GZNliplKNRpjuwrH4xmQG9C7XH5QtXMqkdoJSXfy5ty6qXYg2IkrB%2FF%2F8iZMm1b2in9zGURatCoUM4XwuNbTLhVO0VsQeLckYISargvZS6i13xZqnCneran1Zke3CTh6AZorXaKIt1MJdASCjxtQV9q1tiwpYtMcwQREqmnyEof%2Fy5qjdL9moXYHV7zOiEav%2FDuAjxFVcGxOhTIl9iY2to%2FPBCpVYuNoEC4rB5gOe7HeDb0RyGQ%2B1UbhTCaU%2BjEZ26zLY8wGFd4NK6LzGMZYxeUv%2FKcahbvwgxdTZiwM8znCU0dNnpq1xsSRwQexVFrxZSmF9E6Q34FD9Zt48wy8zmdAv6NYzpRzUXIDboOYbcwJfnc%2FEkhvTsJ6GpEDSwom4bt4EWVahCunkNCZCvIDEB5fQqhG3lBPds5nHUc45UpCptw3o%2B9pEZPucSdJZ1HO3REmIeFciA%2BObvlqCgmdbaEbXliRhG6HHSzbO%2B9AdiOehNRj4CYgYOpGOC9SqZx%2BRnjgeLPtKtJU4s08iuTy4ZmdNqVKH5Det3o5iN63fAVqG6dAR2F%2FqKNAmNL0Fo5Gdhkcv%2FE5CJ6K4h1AMKapZDD%2BkShu%2BdeJQIyZ%2FgJ5lrOX0m6L%2B5mXikPg%2FCAf1KwehbZSS8UHzfPFTDGc%2B9lm%2FSVgOxSx1dVBDKglAu42ZIESsC%2BqBMRj%2Fn3Disb2056zOX5ugkjE5PZJg7w6BGm4CM73Z0tkCVOqXcvn4wkEbvkBykQ%2BoUz0OhGevfW2WzJ2DyGcfJ8IxWk%2FoeBwzbWKK4q3TzxWqZxYP%2FEYpMTD3pcwQCLeAK%2FF47H%2BuTCnRTdDwWyx6N1yMZC5Us1Q%2FO3QWOqQyVI1NCYOD2r7eIhPOd8VNNdG7W2Z0gRqXhCispGpUxECGE5yFVXPzpuPOj%2Bd8PDTg9BOBSoBlgZnBc6tWJudppqvz5cLUZiLapfVVM7uq97dWIfPWY4FPD4s3%2FDJNpWpr1mj2%2B5MfV6g8nRp8FdwlEQ2AQxlr9hRUqWv7mKbdV0seldezya928hbp4fFWxwddyyYg%2BvDWkl2GfBjqNKQE4i38T6xN%2FSaoQ7oo1eqmUqklD3VIlssW7Z3AygXWaZJthbUbzu4JCuA%2FahSLiSlxQQ4FYiZHiLErfTJV%2FOZcqTiWB%2Fs26vQyuU0sO%2BXk00J%2B4VqcNFVH%2Bw%2FE1TeY%2FPlYCWthVwh4voTszEPBao2BaoPOwXqq2nPHrbpDWIGyyIX%2BFym0n9VCdMgS4mKvXlChX8YKBFiHwoSFW4%2FzPahkM8Nah8qgk0V4SG3DwW5%2FlDah0JeyJT71vP524eKvVNDJZWdGvywfzqROx5Gh1zwXh19HO8pcNIXOdC0Er4O96vg5XjkKAgZgQ91uKFjJ6yFitapB9QBCC41PHsdmsccBFZUeh1u09f2dbMh2HFjft66NPqH6WcIyACswph9VghXI9vA%2BfnW6fMJn3h3j6DifGuXhNsh7BLbuxCKGaFvuZ7bKuaaozbX0Add9B59wUj0jp975HjmMWswYVyTLNgP45pCNSnX5MBHg8VdCOCX18Ar8filiNRLeCmu1R6VhvQcZeJzugmr%2FamAfk9vcecuA26R3WOi8Qz5OFH3zmHU3kFwoKEY7aa4dVHVVJks%2FzIVDh4kh0cZxkRpOQhC4gBy2CFMsYp3WE0YwlRz0D65Jg0nIXw7p5QWjxRKON0wtHkq%2ByCelOapCqVKphBBqHGLbvaXOQ3IezpQdIG%2BF5ShC59SGILyt%2FT%2BAVN0EStyC40hy6xQeaiD3nIhQnwVFvRW7bXq1cKwZDfZwq8wmlR7TuSIKq9C0PJm54SplJbfFcqVTCl8oyCqTWo1DHNYFvSensXQiF44tcN3EWWy9ZM10mQoTQda1STUgwPlpHO6pMthS5rizukWytVMpc9aPapRdwEldVgZZI4uc2n3kCygFCQR3xxsnTIfkLqwzlpLaS8OIVfot3LSbpCyf%2FRxb9Bz%2FFugJKW2HPmYJU54P3lnsSA3RLFqCGnvomZhjFwOE664eUEhJ%2BAtgCKQk2raY7js3S2r1O6WD4tgyVEWbiSMFs0DBFOKFgWez5TCl4lb7bnTvvQJhpA90HD4QuXYKNLqEIUplzjMD7RRpMtp2iiBz2cqxQjUcwXogLujdy4HneMkBxWh8863Q8OL2YR8n%2B0F8btWqOLe9SPRJ0Cprcs3tTZeHU5CkgznrwGljo68a3JI5Dvjk5d8TlhBdOsAIx7dBD4jCJy5Bvby2WRd8a%2FMDWI%2B91jOV9JiPnMQoYlJqtGzZC9ez4mjLttBcNJnuz37REl7B14IBN8TLyRN3ZB1FBQ6b%2BAmZuyrARoGZxBJfzj8dIDCOWytAnYftPUbHRI5A3EOMFl2%2FtxitCJ%2Bi2xEZfZzoWWdoWc%2BBcH%2BLfSZWlqaajR8%2BmOmyfAeYejLzjcerDgWij8h4lisDEscA1f201uCBklk3EpBaxzRJJK0S4TS58hehmN33rHFD%2F94OVCYDlEywiFIQW5xj0Bx1raoD0qobFF60PJU6rOH5yMjT5XqsOQpaOVkAwXbYcYt7spJawjh%2BxfYTZqmzXNCdTIRmiZARFUKtUmWCHke%2FlCE6sVKn%2B1FHxURKuZKwxKhwI3lLH4OMUhxp5WsUUSRIsoc9R7LnkiWjnjEI8QknfCVpw%2FNkilTovATIlOF8nbLlFUSH2aZYsuUOYoI9fqUcRqjLiWXqGN2EfyyLMnKhtwIs1En2bp55pUPpapebPQp8X9kpKpYHJZUVcHT%2Ffg7xFjF3d7WGkhEwXLt1RH2anLxOuErKyFm62MhIvah8TLFbDX%2FEyJmFWFYYha0CwH2zKx9ysIMWNyaBWskYXLW0zIRtMMN6lpyMfvInAGVloiPrXO2YQuxY6dMIQt46UMRqxfz1NYYj7KIlXJDy8pfBpNRGD3EmsU90sgaTAwpcy3a0QZ7ObmsnQwQmxCjdiZU3h5%2Bs5bSHnJFgT40Jmgmsk8FWiZwBwStO6M1Oy3VYOvP4macS3wlU4y0vsduDs9BnjRXD%2BM5yWXZwAdkkZvWPnLH%2FW8wRIy%2Bo9xRa99a0vpDcj4A%2BhOBtgkrT9uIn2vK20F1bHErT0uFXL8CAadFt6DcvuTWsY15L7H0HEapwBNWqYDI4bY5vL3w8OoFiuXExTdBq%2F1tjIVVDMRd7V8q8JlKPhI53ZqBgwxNIdhrf3Vp%2BJAU3pQqKRTeBEkWPkUrVckq95Msp0VXsuxLlGR5L22nZOG2hyxZJTFxJU6QZNkYS1eyKplKeMEv26xbUGVfX1QMSCp03J8Pn4RJEWpwIm1%2BF1Q4KtmOSSqFoyUBSVm4wpMc1%2BTB%2BFBmD2P6UL5%2BDS6wYa8E6oJdvgdtJFUIdqmrTrw2zurEEHWClE9%2F6Sbpc5hKiJuqLwlIJfRbukm16tKVuMCW80uUwiHPlUH1wkedb%2F0PWPfTBgWLDjl6IwLnaEujU28pqNe7zS9uZz1rla90INRUf6aEYI%2BmSk1Fuot%2FztOcSZF1JE9%2B%2FDjQaGtqjfThnd4cgcM2IEmFQKnMZwpF5yj18MZJWL27ZqFlpOZKzkfs89XXZenudBNOyBsIRs%2FJNFjEyNvM8d214OO7k5wr23vieT1KENpH4C6AE%2BfuG%2BYR9zVJa8tZfFa7GnIm9yL4hN%2FJ6oviFj4z3tlzj89UqdrXgBY8Na981a555T3brXzgG1GyLpKTAxgiysUUDkgl6SYLIUuiirx1zJiEJZuiAacJB8mN20qcncb9SJDPIDz20KBfkx6a5HmbJnl%2BIJr8P%2F6SvbiOrgAA";
```

if we send a postData using the viewstate by hardcoding that string into the post data everything works fine, however when we do a string.format("Viewstate={0}",Viewstate); the post data does not work.  It seems as if the string.format is somehow stripping something out of the viewstate and we can not figure it out.  Anyone ever experience this?

Comment: Can you compare the string you get after string.format with the string you hardcode? Check for differences.

Comment: When we compare the strings it shows they are the same, but the postdata returns a 500 error if we do the string.format and lets us through if we hard code.

Comment: `ViewState` is a special post data which is treated differently and ASP.NET performs various checks and validation. Use reflector and capture the requests and compare them, or post here and we have a look.

Comment: Could be to do with the way ASP.NET is encrypting/decrypting the viewstate - i.e. the key could be changing, you may be doing it at the wrong point in the lifecycle perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK ASP.NET [hashes the viewstate by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , and adds the hash value to the end.
i think that when you hardcoded the value it inclided the hash, and when you accessed it
by property it did not, and that`s why it fails.

Comment: you can [turn off](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableviewstatemac(v=VS.90).aspx) the hashing of the view state by using the Page.EnableViewStateMac property and try again. This however is a big security hazard.